# django-tables2: perform an action on click of a row

Tags: django, onclick, tablerow, django-tables2

How to perform some desired action (like saving some values to a session variable that i can use for loading the next page) when a row is clicked in a table created using django-tables2

I am using to django-tables2 to display some data that is coming from DB

In other words I want my table rows to be clickable

Comment: Did you think about attach some JS Events to the rows?

Comment: @Azd325 thanks for the suggestion I was facing the problem, that the table is generated automatically w/o any `id` so how to get this table in `JS` but I tried putting that as a attribute under the `_class Meta_` in `tables.py` (where we have define the class) file and it works :) thanks